# Как в этом случае прижать grid элементы?

Tags: html, css, css3, css-grid

Как прижать желтый элемент к красному, а сероголубой — к зелёному ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item5 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item6 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item1 {
  height: 120px;
}

.item2 {
  height: 150px;
}

.item3 {
  height: 170px;
}

.item4 {
  height: 190px;
}

.item5 {
  height: 210px;
}

.item6 {
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item5">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item6">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По вертикали? Грид для того и нужен, чтобы так НЕ делать...

Answer (score 0):

Вроде никак с использованием `display: grid;`

Есть такой вариант:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item5 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item6 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-content: stretch;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.item1 {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item5">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item6">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

но с фиксированной высотой всех блоков не прокатит.

Comment: спс ... но это не вариант

Answer (score 0):

По сути строки и стоблцы CSS имеют прямоугольную форму и это никак не поменять. Для того чтобы достичь желаемой разметки есть как минимум 2 варианта, которые не нарушают того, что используется модуль CSS Grid:

- Использовать для элементов Grid (grid items) `position: relative` и задавать нужное смещение.

  ```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .item1 {
    background: red;
  }

  .item2 {
    background: green;
  }

  .item3 {
    background: blue;
  }

  .item4 {
    background: yellow;
    top: -50px;
  }

  .item5 {
    background: lightblue;
    top: -20px;
  }

  .item6 {
    background: lightgreen;
  }

  .item {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
  }

  .item1 {
    height: 120px;
  }

  .item2 {
    height: 150px;
  }

  .item3 {
    height: 170px;
  }

  .item4 {
    height: 190px;
  }

  .item5 {
    height: 210px;
  }

  .item6 {
    height: 230px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item item1">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item2">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item3">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item4">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item5">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item6">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  - Создать небольшой (минимальный ряд) через `grid-auto-rows` и задавать элементам высоту через нужный row span (не знаю русского аналога этого словосочетания) через свойство `grid-row`:

  ```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .item1 {
    background: red;
  }

  .item2 {
    background: green;
  }

  .item3 {
    background: blue;
  }

  .item4 {
    background: yellow;
    top: -50px;
  }

  .item5 {
    background: lightblue;
    top: -20px;
  }

  .item6 {
    background: lightgreen;
  }

  .item {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    grid-auto-rows: 10px;
  }

  .item1 {
    grid-row: span 12;
  }

  .item2 {
    grid-row: span 15;
  }

  .item3 {
    grid-row: span 17;
  }

  .item4 {
    grid-row: span 19;
  }

  .item5 {
    grid-row: span 21;
  }

  .item6 {
    grid-row: span 23;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item item1">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item2">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item3">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item4">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item5">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item6">
      <p>lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Вот они прижались, добавил только align-self: flex-end;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item5 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item6 {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item1 {
  height: 120px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.item2 {
  height: 150px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.item3 {
  height: 170px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.item4 {
  height: 190px;
}

.item5 {
  height: 210px;
}

.item6 {
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item5">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item6">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  display: list-item;
  list-style: number inside;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1px; /* сначала зададим высоту строки в 1px для удобства */
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item1 {
  /* далее везде заменяем
  height: #px;
  на
  grid-row: span # */
  grid-row: span 120;
  /* и по итогу имеем тут блок растянутый на 120 строк
  по 1px каждая */
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: span 150;
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: span 170;
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  grid-row: span 190;
  background: yellow;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: span 210;
  background: lightblue;
}

.item6 {
  grid-row: span 230;
  background: lightgreen;
}

/* для автоматически генерируемых блоков оно конечно
не очень удобно, но уж как есть...

можно конечно еще и с
grid-auto-flow: dense
поиграться, но там тоже веселые правила

во первых для него тоже нужно спан"ить блоки(сетка видит
размер детей только в кол-ве строк \ столбцов), а во
вторых... с ним порядок блоков может быть нарушен, как
минимум иногда это важно */
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item5">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item6">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```