# Как "прижать" div друг под другом?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, masonry

Есть верстка стандартного вида на Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Получается вот такая сетка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно, чтобы слои располагались следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посоветовали вот такой вариант:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Он в принципе подходит, вот только на среднем разрешении на планшете при выводе двух столбцов выводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при малом разрешении в один столбец:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда вопрос, есть ли другие варианты "прижать" слои, как на втором рисунке или придется подключать скрипты, наподобие masonry?

Если первый вариант решения вопроса можно поправить, то как лучше это сделать? Можно ли как-то для средних и малых разрешений поменять  расположение слоев, чтобы они шли по порядку 1-2-3-4-5-6, вместо 1-4-2-5-3-6, при этом не добавляя тонны лишнего кода?

Comment: Там всё JS делает, человек спрашивает если можно без этого

Comment: Чем больше мест, где можно задать подобные вопросы, тем больший шанс получить правильные ответы на них. Что касается текущего вопроса, в нем все описано достаточно внятно.

Answer (score 2):

*как вариант display: flex; flex-flow:column wrap;- родителю. Элементы будут прижиматься снизу вверх и при уменьшении высоты родителя переносится на следующие колонки слева направо, по родителю выравниваем align-items: center;- выравнивание по оси Х по центру *

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #757575;
}
.parentNode{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 75px auto;
  background: #ce7358;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
}
.parentNode div {
  width: 80px;
  background: #a1e1c1;
  margin: 8px 5px;
}
.child1{
  height: 90px;
}
.child2{
  height: 75px;
}
.child3{
  height: 100px;
}
.child4{
  height: 95px;
}
.child5{
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentNode">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
  <div class="child5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую так сделать.

Comment: с размерами поиграйся и количеством элементов и с медиа запросами по высоте родителя

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью grid CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
}
```

Полный пример с описанием посмотрите на CodePen + Medium:

- [статья на Medium](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb)
- [пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/QMeZda)

Но будет и несколько строк JavaScript кода.

Буквально 2 дня назад встал такой же вопрос как и у Вас, но пока что не пробовал решить через grid.
Есть ещё вот [такой](https://codeburst.io/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a) способ, но это не сохраняет нужный порядок.

Comment: и так же не работает с фиксированными величинами

Comment: что имеете в виду? Вы посмотрели пример в codepen?

Comment: я вот это имел ввиду : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820343/33274 я тоже пытался прижать ,толи не умею толи криворукий

Comment: посмотрите тут https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/QMeZda

Comment: я смотрел - а теперя берём и удаляем js и всё будет тоже самое ?

Comment: там несколько строк кода в JS, остальное делает CSS и справляется

Comment: на чистый CSS не знаю где можно найти, можно минимизировать JS

Comment: тото .... я это и сам знаю ... а вопрос только о grid без js

Comment: "тонны лишнего кода" нет :)

Comment: автору виднее ... но если не подошёл ответ .. для чего он отмечает его решением ?

Comment: У автора нужно спросить. Может быть требования к производительности задачи менялись.

Comment: Какая? Из кода JS только функция imagesLoaded не понятно откуда берётся

Comment: да да ...я увидел - потому удалил комментарий ..сорри

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению CSS Grid не подходит, так как весь проект на Bootstrap 3. Подключения js также хотелось бы избежать.

Что касается вопроса, почему ответ на другом сервисе был отмечен положительным образом, все просто. Поздно заметил, что при xs и sm вывод контента некорректен, да и задача изменилась.

Comment: Вот здесь есть вариант на css, только мне кажется слои все равно нужно переупорядочить, так как нумерация там идет вертикально, а не горизонтально - https://www.bootply.com/u8utESZd7j