# CSS | Как прижать элементы вертикально

Tags: css, align

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно сделать подобное? Даже не знаю как назвать эту ***прижатость***

Comment: явно дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820518/178576

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , во-первых, перед написанием темы я сделал поиск по данному вопросу и не нашёл никаких тем, потому как название у темы что дали вы - некорректно, поэтому его поиск подобного не дал результатов. Во-вторых, хватит писать бесполезные комментарии, ответ уже был дан и я не понимаю бреда про базу знаний. Было интересно узнать другие способы решения этой задачи, вот и задал вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD** @MaximLensky дал хороший вариант:

В один общий блок сразу пихаются все остальные блоки, а общему даются свойства:

• Задает количество столбиков: `column-count: 5;`

• Указывает отступы между столбиками: `column-gap: 0;`

• Задает бордеры между столбиками `column-rule: 1px solid #123;`

За счет column-count оно само уже определяет, кому-куда встать, в зависимости от контента. Единственный минус, что вы не можете какой-то блок наверняка поставить в верхнем ряде (а во втором примере - можно)

Везде добавлены `-webkit-` и `-moz-` , чтобы наверняка:

```js
//Сюда можете не вникать, сделано для наполнения блоков случайным текстом.

(function(){
  const inner = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');
  const str = "Test, ";
  for(let i = 0; i < inner.length; i++){
    let x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50);
    for(let u = 0; u < x; u++){
      inner[i].innerHTML += str;
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.column {
  column-count: 5; -webkit-column-count: 5; -moz-column-count: 5;
  column-rule: 1px solid #123; -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #123; -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #123;
  column-gap: 0; -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #123; -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #123;
}

.inner {border-bottom: 1px solid red; margin: 0;width: 100%}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Второй вариант:**

Свойство `display: flex` расставляет все внутренние элементы горизонтально рядом друг с другом. А вам остается сделать 5 таких горизонтальных div, и внутри каждого из них разместить другие обычные блоки, которые в свою очередь и так занимают 100% ширины своего родительского блока.

```css
div {border: 1px solid red; margin: 2px;}
.H50 {height: 50px;}
.H30 {height: 30px;}
.flexy {width: 20%; border: none;}
.flexbox {display: flex; border: 1px solid #123; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="H50"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
    <div class="H50"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="H50"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="H50"></div>
    <div class="H50"></div>
    <div class="H50"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="H30"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexy">
    <div class="H50"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
    <div class="H30"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть один минус. Без маргинов - на месте стыка у блоков получается двойной бордер. Если захочется плотно расставить - надо будет заморочиться с border-top, border-bottom, border-left, border-right.

Comment: я подскажу - column-count

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо, и не знал о нем... но он же только для текста работает, но не блоков?

Comment: работает для всего ...

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YMRyoP -вот пример , модифицируй и дай ответ

Comment: проблема с текстом решается так : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609205/330688

Comment: @MaximLensky, Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Для подобных целей можно использовать [css-grid](https://html5book.ru/css-grid/):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 35px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.grid-item {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}
.item2,
.item5,
.item11 {
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}
.item3,
.item6,
.item12 {
  grid-row: 5 / 8;
}
.item4,
.item7,
.item13 {
  grid-row: 8 / 11;
}
.item8 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
.item8 {
  grid-row: 3 / 6;
}
.item9 {
  grid-row: 6 / 9;
}
.item14 {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
.item15 {
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
}
.item16 {
  grid-row: 7 / 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item item1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item3"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item6"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item7"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item8"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item9"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item10"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item11"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item12"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item13"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item14"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item15"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item16"></div>
</div>
```