# Можно ли сделать чтобы колонки bootstrap 4 прилипали друг к другу, если у соседних блоков разная высота?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap4

Есть ли способ не оборачивая в дополнительные обертки [блок 1 + блок 3] и [блок 2 + блок 4] сделать так, чтобы 3 блок прилип к 1 и между ними не было расстояния?

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3 align-items-start">
      <div class="col-6 py-3"> 1 Здесь одна строка</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">2 А <br> здесь <br> много <br>строк</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">3 Здесь тоже одна</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">4 А здесь не важно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: уберите класс `align-items-start` - это из-за него первый блок не растягивается во всю высоту

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974547/css-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/974553#974553 - Вариант с `column-count`, но если один блок окажется больше, чем остальные 3 вместе, то он попадет на одну сторону, а все три - в другую.

Comment: @mymedia а я и не хочу, чтобы он растягивался во всю высоту, я хочу, чтобы 3 блок сместился вверх, как если бы 1 и 3 были обернуты в общий див

Answer (score 0):

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3 align-items-start">
      <div class="col-6 py-3 "> 1 Здесь одна строка</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3 order-1">2 А <br> здесь <br> много <br>строк</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3 ">3 Здесь тоже одна</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3 order-2">4 А здесь не важно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

да вот пример так же вот ссылка https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ Вам надо поиграть с **boostrap** классом **order**

Comment: Вероятно, вопрос про то, как это сделать динамически?

Comment: нет, я не хотел их менять местами, я хотел убрать вертикальное расстояние между блоками 1 и 3

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я правильно понял.

Если Вам нужно такое, как на скриншоте (ширина блоков одинаковая, а высота выравнивается по соседнему, то, посмотрите вот этот код). Я не претендую, что это правильное решение, но может натолкнёт на мысли)

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; background-color: #a4a4a4;">
         123123123
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; background-color: #a4a4a4;">
        Lorem 
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; background-color: #a4a4a4;">
        123123123
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; background-color: #a4a4a4;">
        123123123
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
      <div class="col-6 py-3"> 1 Здесь одна строка</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">2 А <br> здесь <br> много <br>строк</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">3 Здесь тоже одна</div>
      <div class="col-6 py-3">4 А здесь не важно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```