# Flex. Как сделать обтекание картинок картинками? Без текста

Tags: css, flexbox, float

Как сделать обтекание блока блоком, через `flex`? Есть группа картинок обернутые в тег `a`. Как из этого(песочница) - сделать этот вариант(картинка).
Спасибо!

[песочница](https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-float-uufzd)

[image: пример]

Comment: Мне кажется никак. Но можно сделать три колонки `.column`. В эти три кололнки положить картинки (допустим по 10 в каждую). Этому классу дать `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start:` А родителю для этих трех елементов `.column` дать `flex-direction: row`

Comment: Используйте masonry:
https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/
https://codepen.io/tobiasahlin/pen/JVmLRa

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974547/css-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/974553#974553 - здесь та же история, только блоки вместо картинок)